# Class does not exist in @Apply layer using Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

just what I think will be a simple solution, but I can't find it. I have found similar problems with people using the Hover style and a white space right after, witch is wrong. But it is not my case.

I'm building my firts React and Tailwind application, when trying to create and use a custom style, i receive this error:

The `w-50` class does not exist. If `w-50` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .nav-link {
    @apply w-50 h-50 rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-600 grid place-items-center;
  }
}
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,css}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, after study a little more about Tailwind, Tailwind has a already fix build-in values to operate with. As you can see in it's mainly documentation above:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

However it is possible to set new values in the tailwind.config.js file if you really need something those values does not embrace.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you have tried to use the `w-50` class that does not resolve to a class that Tailwind knows about.

Again, as per the error, if it is a custom class, [consider defining it in a `@layer base/components/utilities`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer) like:

```css
@layer utilities {
  .w-50 {
    …
  }
}
```

Or, consider checking you have `50` as a value for the `width` core utilities. In `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    width: {
      '50': 'Your value here',
    },
  },
  // …
};
```

or

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extends: {
      width: {
        '50': 'Your value here',
      },
    },
  },
  // …
};
```

Make sure it is defined at `theme.width.50` if you don't want any of the default `width` values to be available. Otherwise, make sure it is defined at `theme.extends.width.50`.